# SQL query Calculate hourly bonus for different roles combined

Tags: mysql, subquery, common-table-expression

There is a table having employee wise work history. Rank of some employees upgraded and their payment is calculated based in their rank and working hours.
Also they get bonus payment if total working hours go beyond 25 hours.

For a specific period of time( say 30 days), if any employee have worked on two or more roles(rank).

How to calculate bonus amount if total working hours falling for combined roles.

Example

```
EmpId -  Date -     WorkHours - Role

1001   2023-05-01 - 11       Trainee

1001   2023-05-03 - 9        Trainee

1001   2023-05-06 - 8        Jr.Dev
1002   2023-05-02 - 6        Jr.Dev
1002   2023-05-05 - 11       Jr.Dev
1002   2023-05-06 - 10       Jr.Dev 
1002   2023-05-07 -  7 -     Sr.Dev
1004
```

Role wise Payment amount for

```
Role - Amount 
Trainee - 1000
Jr.Dev - 1500
Sr.Dev - 2500
```

Bonus- 30% extra for respective role hours

How to calculate total payment for employee 1001 in MySql

Required calculation as below-

```
1001 - 1000*20 + 1500*8 + 450*3 (30%)
1002 - 1500*27 + 450*2 + 2500*7 + 750*7
```